# MongoDB $divide on aggregate output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, divide

Is there a possibility to calculate mathematical operation on already aggregated computed fields?

I have something like this:

```
([
        {
                "$unwind" : {
                        "path" : "$users"
                }
        },
        {
                "$match" : {
                        "users.r" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                        }
                }
        },
        {
                "$group" : {
                        "_id" : "$users.r",
                        "count" : {
                                "$sum" : 1
                        }
                }
        },
])
```

Which gives an output as:

```
{ "_id" : "A", "count" : 7 }
{ "_id" : "B", "count" : 49 }
```

Now I want to divide 7 by 49 or vice versa.

Is there a possibility to do that? I tried $project and $divide but had no luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: if the fields `A` and `B` are fixed then it can be easily done by `$project` else you have to capture the result of `$group`(*with `.toArray()` at the end of your query*) into a variable and then create your result by looping and creating a new object.

Comment: Hi @vikscool, actually I am new to MongoDB, could you please help me with that $project thing and yes both the fields are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it looks like you are assuming result count to be 2 only. In that case I can assume `users.r` can have only 2 values(apart from null).

The simplest thing I suggest is to do this arithmetic via javascript(if you're  using it in mongo console) or in case of using it in progam, use the language you're using to access mongo) e.g.

```
var results = db.collection.aggregate([theAggregatePipelineQuery]).toArray();
print(results[0].count/results[1].count);
```

**EDIT:** I am sharing an **alternative** to above approach because OP commented  about the constraint of not using javascript code and the need to be done only via query. Here it is

```
([
       { /**your existing aggregation stages that results in two rows as described in the question with a count field **/ },
       { $group: {"_id": 1, firstCount: {$first: "$count"}, lastCount: {$last: "$count"} 
       },
       { $project: { finalResult: { $divide: ['$firstCount','$lastCount']} } }
])

//The returned document has your answer under `finalResult` field
```

Comment: @sunyb hope this answer helped you. Please upvote if it did and accept as answer(tick mark on the side o answer). This will help other SO readers.

Comment: Yes, that's true .. it will work like this but I am looking to use that in MongoDB charts. So I need to have a single aggregate statement.

Comment: In that case you case use `$divide` to get the results. You can get both `count` values in one document by using another group function and use `$first` and `$last`. If you want to me write the query, share the sample documents to test for.

Comment: @sunnyb I have updated the answer, checkout details under Edit section. I hope this helps, hope this works.